# Android GCM Intent Service - How to get Application class

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a self implemented Application class.

I'm trying to get a reference to it from my application GCMIntentService.

From Some reason it returns null:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private AppVariables app;
    private GCMMessageReceiver gcmMessageReceiver;

    public GCMIntentService()
    {
        super(GCMManager.SENDER_ID);
        this.app = (AppVariables) getApplication();
        this.gcmMessageReceiver = new GCMMessageReceiver(app);
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from `onRegistered()` method.

```
    @Override
    public void onRegistered(Context context, String registration) {
         this.app = (AppVariables) context;
         DeviceRegistrar.registerWithServer(context, registration);
    }
```

Because we can't change constructor `GCMIntentService()` to pass context there to use.